# What is "Black Care"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What do the words in bold mean? Wells's short story Catastrophe

> Then, knowing that **Black Care** was lurking in the dusky corners of the shop, he lit the three lamps early and set to refolding his **cotton prints**, the most vigorous and least meditative proceeding of which he could think

Comment: We need more context to know who/what Black Care is and what the cotton prints are. Please make more of an effort in your questions to give us the information we need

Comment: It's an "unusual" metaphoric usage referring to the fact that Winslow (the subject) was aware that he could easily be overwhelmed by ***negative thoughts, despair*** sitting alone in the dusky shop (that's why he lights the lamps early; darkness is more depressing than well-lit surroundings). To experience "black care" (a phrase with very little currency even when Wells wrote it) isn't so extreme as "Black Dog" (a fairly well-known but dated term for ***clinical depression***).

Comment: ...note that a few sentences further in the narrative  we find *[Winslow] finally went to bed. Minnie was already there. And **there, too, waiting for him**, nudging him gently, until about midnight he was hopelessly awake, **sat Black Care.*** But there were only two people (Winslow and Minnie) in the bedroom. Black Care is an entirely metaphoric entity who only exists in Winslow's head.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what does the word "care" have to do with thoughts?

Comment: SergeyZolotarev - when you experience care (worry) then it is necessarily in your thoughts, because worrying is anxious thinking.

Comment: By the way, I don't know why it's been closed. I did provide context. Did you want me to quote the entire paragraph? It would not help one bit ‍♂️

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev: As Colin points out, ***Black Care** is not an established phrase, and its meaning may or may not be clarified within the story.* And I already searched the entire text to establish that the only other reference is as per my previous comment. Feasibly Wells knew the expression already, but he might just have coined it himself anyway. I've voted to reopen because I completely agree with your most recent comment, but there probably isn't really any more to say about it even if the Q is reopened. Whether "known" or not, it's just metaphoric "sadness / depression".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cotton prints* are pieces of material (or possibly clothes) of cotton, printed with a design or pattern.

*Black Care* is not an established phrase, and its meaning may or may not be clarified within the story. I guess it means either depression, or fear of the dark.

Comment: It means deep gloom about the failure of his business.